# Manpage keep exiting with status 127

Tags: linux, manpage

Can not open manual page of any utility and get exit status of 127.

```
command :- man man
result :- sh: line 1: bat: command not found
man: command exited with status 127: sed -e '/^[[:space:]]*$/{ N; /^[[:space:]]*\n[[:space:]]*$/D; }' | LESS=-ix8RmPm Manual page man(1) ?ltline %lt?L/%L.:byte %bB?s/%s..?e (END):?pB %pB\%.. (press h for help or q to quit)$PM Manual page man(1) ?ltline %lt?L/%L.:byte %bB?s/%s..?e (END):?pB %pB\%.. (press h for help or q to quit)$ MAN_PN=man(1) sh -c col -bx | bat -l man -p
```

Comment: check that your path includes man and sed

Comment: Both sed and man are reside in /usr/bin so thats present in the path after checking it with echo $PATH.

Comment: It's this bit at the end that's reporting the error `bat -l man -p`

Comment: Ok , so did i have to remove it? if i have to where this file has been stored with these lines are mentined.

Comment: That end bit doesn't make any sence, 'bat' isn't a a standard command and needs to be on your path and in addition I would expect to see a '|' between the 2 commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same issue. I tried to edit the script at /usr/bin/man but it was mostly garbled nonsense. I noticed that 'newbie' commented that bat isn't a standard command so I tried installing "bat" and trying man again, this time it worked. You should try installing bat.